# Modify formula using indirect to work with autofill?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Here are the first few rows:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!G:G"),MATCH(INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!C12"),INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!C:C"),"0"))
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!G:G"),MATCH(INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!C13"),INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!C:C"),"0"))
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!G:G"),MATCH(INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!C14"),INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!C:C"),"0"))
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!G:G"),MATCH(INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!C15"),INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!C:C"),"0"))
```

If I try to autofill down (~50 rows) it just repeats C12, C13, C14, C15, C12, C13, etc, etc.

I need the `INDIRECT` to reference a sheet name by a cell value.

I don't really want to change all 50+ of these.  How can I rewrite this formula to respect autofill?

Comment: Just drag the first row alone down

Comment: @SuperSam the problem is that by using the INDIRECT and the C12 being in the quotes it will not change as it is dragged down.

Comment: If you need the value in C12 not just C12 you can remove the quotes, for all references you can remove quotes to use the values not the references it will be =INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!G:G"),MATCH(INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!"&C12),INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!C:C"),"0"))

Comment: Follow this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) for more about Indirect and quotes

Comment: @SuperSam now the INDIRECT looks to the value in C12 of the active sheet for another string for the cell reference, Inside of C12 you would need a String of a cell address to tell INDIRECT where to go.  For example if I put `B12` in A1 and put `INDIRECT(A1)` in A2 it would return the value from B12 not A1.  Indirect takes a string and turns it into a reference.  In the formula above it the string would be the value in I2 and the Value in C12 combined to form a string that must be a reference.

Comment: You mean in C12 you have a reference or sheetname but I$2 is the sheetname

Comment: Try Scott's formula but check the row number where you use it

Comment: @SuperSam c12 would have the cell reference.  Lets assume you have `Sheet1` in I2, and in c12 you had E15.  With the Indirect set up like yours the final string would be `'Sheet1'!E15` because `"'"&I$2&"'!"&C12`  would return the value of c12 not C12 itself.  That is why I used a number that can be increased.  `"'"&I$2&"'!C" & ROW(1:1)+11` will return a string `'Sheet1!C12` in the first.  The Row(1:1) will change to Row(2:2) and so forth as it is dragged down.

Comment: just write row() and in which row is your formula

Comment: @SuperSam I use Row(1:1) so that it does not matter in which row the formula starts.  Row(1:1) returns 1 and Row(2:2) returns 2.  So no matter in which row it starts 1,2 or 100 it will start looking at Cell C12 and increase by 1 each row it is dragged down.

Comment: Just write row() it does increase one but the 11 matters i have tried it and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the first cell and copy down:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!G:G"),MATCH(INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!C" & ROW(1:1)+11),INDIRECT("'"&I$2&"'!C:C"),"0"))
```

It will now increase one row each time it is copied down.